# Is it possible to use a string value to specify the name of a parameter's string accessor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I'm feeling like I'm missing something very important from my past experiences, however, here it is:

I am designing an end-user report designer using DevExpress for clients within my corporation. Since these are being generated dynamically, I would like to give clients the opportunity to have free range over what they are putting on the report. Instead of hard-coding all of the available values, I'm using a `StartsWith` and a `Substring` to retrieve the name of the control. I would like to use this string value to specify which parameter field they would need. I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this correctly or if I'm way off track, hoping someone can take another look and give me some suggestions.

Any information will be appreciated.

Maybe I need a dictionary or some sort of interface? Code snippet of what I currently have is below:

```
private static void BuildReportHeader(Notice notice, XRControl control)
        {
            if (control.Name.StartsWith("lbl"))
            {
                string elementName = control.Name.Substring(3);

                XRLabel label = (XRLabel)control;
                label.Text = notice.{elementName};
            }
        }
```

Obviously, this doesn't work or compile as it currently sits, just looking for a solution to the {elementName} bit so that I can access any field on that specific parameter.

Comment: `notice.{elementName}` << What is it? A property/field/method?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I should have been more clear. Notice is the object and {elementName} would be a property of the Notice object. So, something like Notice.FullName or Notice.Address. I would have a corresponding lblFullName and lblAddress which would line up with those property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to perform this dynamic value lookup: `notice.{elementName}`.

The bellow sample codes assumed that `elementName` exist and it's `public`.

#### If elementName is a property

```
var propertyValue = typeof(Notice).GetProperty(elementName).GetValue(notice);
```

- Please bear in mind that `GetValue` returns an `object`
- The above code assumed that the `elementName` property has a getter

  - If it does not have then you will receive an `ArgumentException`

#### If elementName is a field

```
var propertyValue = typeof(Notice).GetField(elementName).GetValue(notice);
```

- The above code assumed that the `elementName` points to a field

  - If you provide a non-existing field name or a property/method name then you would receive a `NullReferenceException` because `GetField` would return `null`